Bayesian network with partial info (4 nodes)
I have some (conditional) probabilities for a Bayesian network with binary variables, but not all.
My DAG is M->F->Y->C<-F and M->Y and M->C
I know P(M), P(F|M), P(Y|M), P(Y|F), P(Y), P(F), P(C|F) and P(C|Y). I also know that P(C|not F, not Y) = 0.
But I don't know P(C|M, Y, F).
I can do a random search and fill out some of the conditional probabilities and check whether my (estimated) probabilities match the probabilities I know.
But are there better ways to estimate this?
I am also ok if I get intervals (approximate solution) for some of the probabilities of interest.

if you don't know it, you should learn it no? do you have data to learn such conditional?

yes I want to learn or estimate it, I have no data, I can simulate some though
